# Create an instance on a particular volume type in OpenStack

Tags: openstack, cinder, glance, nova

I'm not able to figure out, how to *easily* boot new instance while creating new Cinder volume from Glance image on particular volume type.

I know I can create cinder volume with specific volume type using `openstack volume create` with `--type` parameter, or set property `cinder_img_volume_type` for glance image... But how to do this with `openstack server create`? Why is `cinder_img_volume_type` property ignored when creating a new instance and use default_volume_type instead? Without this it won't be possible to use Horizon and we will have to instruct our customers to use the "harder way" (cli tools combination as specified before) to achieve this.

Component versions used:

- Cinder: 2:8.1.1-0ubuntu3
- Glance: 2:12.0.0-0ubuntu2
- Nova: 2:13.1.4-0ubuntu4.3
- Horizon (openstack-dashboard): 2:9.1.1-0ubuntu1

(they are older, I know :)

thank you!

Comment: I've partially figured this out so I can use Horizon in two steps: 1. Create volume from an image. 2. Launch VM from this volume.; I wasn't aware of this feature, respectively I thought it will create a copy of the volume. Although it would be still great to be able to launch VM only in one step.